# two if blocks vs if and else if

Tags: if-statement

```
if(button.getText().equals("Hello")){
     button.setText("Hello World");
}
else if(button.getText().equals("Hello World")){
     button.setText("Hello");
}
```

the code above works, while the second doesn't:

```
if(button.getText().equals("Hello")){
     button.setText("Hello World");
}
if(button.getText().equals("Hello World")){
     button.setText("Hello");
}
```

This one goes straight to the second if block

I don't understand how it is different from the first one, it should go first to the first if block but it just skips it

I hope you can explain me this

here is the full code:

```
package javaapplication4;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JavaApplication4 implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JavaApplication4 gui = new JavaApplication4();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Hello");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
        if(button.getText().equals("Hello")){
            button.setText("Hello World");
        }
        if(button.getText().equals("Hello World")){
            button.setText("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't go to the first one? Have you tried debugging it? It probably goes to the first one and then to the second one afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation. First one:

```
if(button.getText().equals("Hello")){ //let's say it's true, so the text is "Hello"
     button.setText("Hello World"); //now you change the text to "Hello World"
}
else if(button.getText().equals("Hello World")){ //this line is not executed because of "else" keyword, it means that it will be checked ONLY if the first statement was false
     button.setText("Hello"); //this line is not executed
}
```

Second one:

```
if(button.getText().equals("Hello")){ //let's say it's true, so the text is "Hello"
     button.setText("Hello World"); //now the text is "Hello World"
}
if(button.getText().equals("Hello World")){ //it's true because you changed the text
     button.setText("Hello"); //so this line changes text again, back to "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that +1

Answer (score 1):

First one it will stop after the first if because text = Hello. It wont go in to the else if statement.

But with the second one it will also check the second if.
First it checks if text = Hello -> that is true, so it wil change in Hello world.
After that the second if will check if text = Hello world, which it is.

Comment: Probably yea, sorry. New to stackoverflow.

Comment: @HuyNguyen No, not really. The question provided all of the code, and is just asking for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in the second one is that both blocks are executed, something the else statement prevents.

At first, the text is equal to "Hello". After the first if statement, it is changed to "Hello World".

It then moves on to the second statement, and now that the text is "Hello World", it executes this statement too, changing the text back to "Hello".

This doesn't happen in the first example because `else if` means that the condition will only be checked for if the preceding if statement gave a false result.